# when mocking Getting ClassCastException Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing unit test code for class CardManager.java,

while executing unit test code i am getting:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

**CardManager.java**

for the below line i coded the when condition for unit test code.

```
ArrayList arr1= (ArrayList) getPanCardUtil().validatePanCard("" , "" , "" , "");
```

**cardManagerTest.java**

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();

when(cardManager.validate("" , "" , "" , "").thenReturn(abc);
```

**Validate.java**

```
public List<String> validate("" , "" , "" , "");
```

Comment: It'll be impossible for anyone to help unless you post more complete code. It's not obvious what the link between validatePanCard and cardManager.validate is.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the line

```
ArrayList arr1= (ArrayList) getPanCardUtil().validatePanCard("" , "" , "" , "");
```

should be changed to

```
List arr1= getPanCardUtil().validatePanCard("" , "" , "" , "");
```

In the code you've posted there is no reference to a `LinkedList` nor any other reference to the method `validatePanCard`, but if you're using both, you want to avoid downcasting, and keep everything at the interface level as much as you can.

If you post more complete code, it might be possible to isolate the real issue.

Also, it might be helpful to tell us what mocking framework your using.  I suspect (just from syntax) that it's Mockito.

Comment: this code is already existing                               ArrayList arr1= (ArrayList) getPanCardUtil().validatePanCard("" , "" , "" , "");                                                          i am writing unit test code for this line using Mockito framework

Comment: Sometimes in order to successfully test code you have to change the code you're testing.  If you want help writing a test without changing the tested code, you definitely need to supply more information.

Comment: code for that i am writing the unit test code is --> ArrayList arr1= (ArrayList) getPanCardUtil().validatePanCard("String v1" , "String v2" , "String v3" , "String v4");                                               Unit Test code written to satisfy the above line is --> List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();

when(cardManager.validate(String v, String v2, String v3, String v4).thenReturn(abc);
and the calling method validate is returning  --> public List<String> validate(String v, String v2, String v3, String v4) {}

Comment: Please put the code snippets *in the question*.  They're thoroughly illegible in comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provide its not clear what the method is cardManager.validate("","","","") is (in cardmanagerTest.java)?

I suspect that you have a method in CardManager.java which implements the method validate of Validate.java

```
public LinkedList<String> validate(String v, String v2, String v3, String v4) {}
```

And your test case is failing because it doesnt match the return type of this method, but does match the interface definition in validate.java.  You should just return a List type.

```
public List<String> validate(String v, String v2, String v3, String v4) {}
```